# How to know when I close my app?

Tags: android, bluetooth

My question is simple, I tried disable the bluetooth for my app when the user close the app.
I need that if the user is with the app in background, the bluetooth maintain active, but if the user slide the app out of screen, the bluetooth closes.

I know how disable the bluetooth.

```
if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
    mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
}
```

Works perfectly, but I need call that 3 lines when the user close the app, I tried with `onDestroy`, `onPause`, `onStop`, but noone works for me.

`onDestroy` method is called when the user touch back button and the task go for background.
`onPause` method is called when the user touch the recents button, but the app is not closed.
`onStop` method same of `onPause`.

So... How to know when the user close the app?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method to check if the app is running in background or not.

```
private boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {

                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;

            }
        }

        return isInBackground;
    }
```

This method returns true if the app is running in background.Then you can enable or disable bluetooth accordingly.
Also you can set a flag in your onResume and onPause methods of the BaseActivity which is extended by all other activitues so that you can check the flags to know whether app is running or not.

Comment: That method also creates pointless `Handler`s, and shows a popup. You could clean it up a little to match the desired / advertised functionality. The remaining problem then is that the method still doesn't help on it's own. Because it will return `false` from inside `onStop` etc since the app is still in foreground.

Comment: The method checks whether app is in background.It returns true only if it is running in background.That's why i mentioned to use the return value accordingly

Comment: But how & where can OP use the method? The method will not tell you Inside the mentioned activity lifecycle methods whether the app is *going to be* background afterwards.

Comment: For that,you have to write a Service class

Comment: `IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND` does not mean the app is in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

> Make a **BaseActivity** and override its OnPause() method and extend
>   every Activity from BaseActivity .

I would also like to mention that onPause() is fired even when switching between multiple activities, so you'd need to track when it's pausing to go to another screen.

Reference : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 0):

If you want Bluetooth disabled when the user exits your activity, disable it in `onBackPressed()`.